# What does Page Life Expectancy say about the instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, memory, page-life-expectancy

I have installed monitoring software on a few SQL Server instances in the environment. I am trying to find bottlenecks and fix some performance issues. I want to find out if some servers need more memory.

I am interested in one counter: page life expectancy. It looks different on every machine. Why does it change often on some instances and what does it mean?

Please take a look at the data from the last week gathered on a few different machines. What can you say about each instance?

Heavily used production instance (1):
[image: Heavily used production instance (1)]

Moderately used production istance (2)
[image: Moderately used production istance (2)]

Rarely used test instance (3)

[image: Rarely used test instance (3)]

Heavily used production instance (4)
[image: Heavily used production instance (4)]

Moderately used test instance (5)
[image: Moderately used test instance (5)]

Heavily used data warehouse (6)
[image: Heavily used data warehouse (6)]

EDIT: Im adding the output of 
    SELECT @@VERSION
for all of these servers:

```
Instance 1: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64) 
Jun 17 2011 00:54:03 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)


Instance 2: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3000.0 (X64) 
Oct 19 2012 13:38:57 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)


Instance 3: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64) 
May 14 2014 18:34:29 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Instance 4: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64) Jun 28 2012 08:36:30 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)


Instance 5: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64) 
May 14 2014 18:34:29 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Instance 6: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64) 
Apr 2 2010 15:48:46 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)
```

I also ran the following query on the machines:

```
SELECT DISTINCT memory_node_id
FROM sys.dm_os_memory_clerks
```

and it returned 2 or 3 rows for each server:

```
Instance 1: 0; 64; 1
Instance 2: 0; 64
Instance 3: 0; 64
Instance 4: 0; 64
Instance 5: 0; 64
Instance 6: 0; 64; 1
```

What does it mean? Do these servers run NUMA?

Comment: Instance 2 has SQL Server 2012 and others are SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: The scale of the graphs doesn't really help. It would be more interesting to see how close to zero the busy servers get during the day.

Comment: I wish I could get more detailed data. I used Solarwinds Database Performance Monitor and there is no way to export data to a file. The only way to do that is to query its database but the structure is neither normalized nor easy to grasp.

Comment: In order to help you understand the sudden drops: When a big scan of uncached data is executed lots of pages are being evicted to make room for the new pages. It's a modified LRU algorithm. New pages drop old ones.

Comment: Instances 2 and 6 use NUMA, others don't.

Answer (score 8):

Taken from MSDN:- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189628.aspx

*Page life expectancy - Indicates the number of seconds a page will stay in the buffer pool without references.*

SQL always looks for data pages in memory. If a data page is not in memory SQL will have to go to disk (perform a physical IO operation) in order to retrieve the data that it needs to fulfil a request. If your PLE counter is low that indicates that data pages in memory are regularly been overwritten with new pages coming from physical IO operations. Physical IO operations are expensive meaning that the performance of your SQL instance will be adversely affected. So you will want your PLE counter to be as high as possible.

**Ignore any advice that you see online that mentions 300 as a good threshold for this counter**

This threshold comes from the days when memory was limited (think 32-bit systems). Now we have 64-bit systems which can have TBs of RAM so this advice is very out of date.

First thing, have you limited SQL's memory? If so, how much available memory is left? Can the limit be increased?

Second thing I would be looking for on your servers is, are there any maintenance jobs running? Check for jobs performing index rebuilds, update stats or DBCC CHECKDB operations. These perform a large amount of reads and could be the reason for your PLE flat lining,

Next, as you're using SQL Server 2008 +, you can setup an Extended Event session to capture queries coming in that are performing a large amount of reads. Here's the code to do so:-

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [QueriesWithHighLogicalReads] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_batch_completed(
   ACTION(sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.tsql_stack,sqlserver.username)
     WHERE ([logical_reads]>200000))
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'C:\SQLServer\XEvents\QueriesWithHighLogicalReads.xel')
GO
```

This will capture all queries on your server that perform over 200000 logical reads. I don't know how much memory you have on each server so you may want to tweak that figure. Once this has been created you can start the session by running:-

```
ALTER EVENT SESSION [QueriesWithHighLogicalReads]
ON SERVER
STATE = START;
GO
```

And then query the session by running:-

```
WITH CTE_ExecutedSQLStatements AS
(SELECT
[XML Data],
[XML Data].value('(/event[@name=''sql_statement_completed'']/@timestamp)[1]','DATETIME')    AS [Time],
[XML Data].value('(/event/data[@name=''duration'']/value)[1]','int')                        AS [Duration],
[XML Data].value('(/event/data[@name=''cpu_time'']/value)[1]','int')                        AS [CPU],
[XML Data].value('(/event/data[@name=''logical_reads'']/value)[1]','int')                   AS [logical_reads],
[XML Data].value('(/event/data[@name=''physical_reads'']/value)[1]','int')                  AS [physical_reads],
[XML Data].value('(/event/action[@name=''sql_text'']/value)[1]','varchar(max)')             AS [SQL Statement]
FROM
    (SELECT 
    OBJECT_NAME              AS [Event], 
    CONVERT(XML, event_data) AS [XML Data]
FROM 
    sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file
('C:\SQLServer\XEvents\QueriesWithHighLogicalReads*.xel',NULL,NULL,NULL)) as v)

SELECT
[SQL Statement]     AS [SQL Statement],
SUM(Duration)       AS [Total Duration],
SUM(CPU)            AS [Total CPU],
SUM(Logical_Reads)  AS [Total Logical Reads],
SUM(Physical_Reads) AS [Total Physical Reads]
FROM
CTE_ExecutedSQLStatements
GROUP BY
[SQL Statement]
ORDER BY
[Total Logical Reads] DESC
GO
```

Be careful when running this! The file can grow quite large in size so test it out on a development instance first. You can set the max. size of the file but I haven't included that here. Here's the MSDN link for Extended Events:- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213147.aspx

Monitor this session routinely and hopefully it should pick up any queries coming in that are flat lining your PLE.

Further reading -

MSDN blog on PLE - [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mcsukbi/sql-server-page-life-expectancy)

Video on setting up Extended Events - https://dbafromthecold.wordpress.com/2014/12/05/video-identifying-large-queries-using-extended-events/
(It's from my own blog so sorry about the shameless self promotion)

Answer (score 4):

Page life expectancy is a measure of how long you can expect a page that has just been read from disk to hang around in memory before it is pushed out by something else or is destroyed (i.e. that page is deallocated on disk to there is no need to keep a copy cached in RAM).

As a general measure, the higher it is the faster your load pattern will be processed because things are being kept in memory. If it is very low this could indicate a performance problem caused by memory starvation.

The reading being low does not always mean there is a problem though: for instance it could be low after a massive one-off glut of processes that used a lot of pages so have them brought in and them dropped to make room for more. Your graph that seems to drop at the end of each day for example, could be caused by nightly administrative jobs (backup, data archiving, other overnight processing).